# React.setState not working in Axios interceptor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have this higher order component that has Axios interceptors:

```js
const withErrorHandler = (Component) => {
    const ErrorHandler = (props) => {
        const [error, setError] = useState(null)


        const reqInterceptor = axios.interceptors.request.use(req => {
            setError(null);
            return req;
        });

        const resInterceptor = axios.interceptors.response.use(res => res, error => {
            console.log(error.response)
            setError(error.response);
        });



        useEffect(() => {
            return () => {
                axios.interceptors.request.eject(reqInterceptor);
                axios.interceptors.response.eject(resInterceptor);
            };
        }, [reqInterceptor, resInterceptor]);

        let alert = ''
        console.log(error)
        if (error) {
            console.log(error)
            alert = <Alert variant="danger" onClose={() => setError(null)} dismissible>
                <Alert.Heading>Oh snap! You got an error!</Alert.Heading>
                <p>
                    Change this and that and try again. Duis mollis, est non commodo
                    luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit.
                    Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum.
                </p>
            </Alert>
        }
        return (
            <>
                {alert}
                <Component {...props} />
            </>
        )
    }
    return ErrorHandler
}

export default withErrorHandler
```

Now I noticed the `console.log` in the response interceptor is logging the correct values but it's as if `setError` is not working.

Comment: What does which `console.log` output? You mentioned it logging in the response interceptor, but you didn't mention if any others also logged anything.

Comment: The console.log right before the if statement logs the formal state of the error which is null

Comment: Works for me: https://codesandbox.io/s/usestate-with-array-forked-2eh3r?file=/src/index.js

Comment: You shouldn't use unintentional side-effect console logs as any accurate measure of state updates. Log the error in an `useEffect` with a dependency on the error state.

Comment: @DrewReese. when I put this. the interceptor in a useEffect it works as expected

Comment: Sorry, that last comment is a bit awkward to read. What are you saying?

Comment: I mean if I put the axios interceptors in a useEffect it works as expected

Comment: Ok, that's probably where you want them anyway so they aren't redeclared as an unintentional side-effect each time the component rerenders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I found the solution to this. The issue was

> React.strict

. I dont know why though, but as soon as i removed it from my index js. it worked as expected

Comment: Are you referring to [React.StrictMode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html)? It helps identify unintentional side-effects. You mentioned moving something into the `useEffect` and it was working as expected. I think you should take this as a strong hint to reinstate the `React.StrictMode` and keep whatever it was in the `useEffect` callback there.

Comment: yeah, thanks . Its better off in the useEffect. To prevent unintentional side effects